# c segmentation fault on memcpy()

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I have a struct with two char arrays. One of the arrays `output_filename[]` is initialised with a filename for example `testdata.dat`. The other array is not initialised.

```
typedef struct _prv_instance_
{
    char output_filename[256];
    char output_filename_serial_log[256];

} prv_instance_t;
```

In a function I create a pointer to this struct. I then want to initialize `output_filename_serial_log[]` using `output_filename[]`. 
So its value would be `testdata_serial_log.txt` i.e. remove the `.dat` and append `_serial_log.txt`.

However, I am getting a seg fault on memcpy? Would anybody know why?

```
prv_instance_t * targetP; /*create pointer*/
targetP = (prv_instance_t *)lwm2m_list_find(objectP->instanceList, instanceId); /*assign struct to pointer*/

    /*Create a filename to store the serial output*/
char filename_ending[] = "_serial_log.txt";
printf("output_filename is %s\n", targetP->output_filename);    
printf("The length of output_filename is %d\n",strlen(targetP->output_filename)); 
printf("Number of bytes to be copied is %d\n",strlen(targetP->output_filename));


memcpy(targetP->output_filename_serial_log, targetP->output_filename, (strlen(targetP->output_filename)-4)); /*copy in string minus .dat*/
strcat(targetP->output_filename_serial_log, filename_ending); /*add on the ending*/
printf("The serial filename is %s\n",targetP->output_filename_serial_log);
```

Comment: You have to zero-terminate the memcpied string if you intend to use the copy with string functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
memcpy(dest, src, strlen(src) - 4);
```

will *not* give you a C-style string since you do not null-terminate it. For example, if the string is `xyzzy.txt\0` in memory, then `dest` will end up with just `xyzzy` followed by arbitrary data.

If you then attempt to `strcat` to `dest`, all bets are off since you are invoking undefined behaviour.

You would be better off with something like:

```
strcpy(dest, src);
dest[strlen(dest) - 4] = '\0';
stcat(dest, "something");
```

(assuming you can guarantee your string will be at least four characters long).

Comment: perhaps I should use `snprintf()` instead and copy the filename into the other array minus the last four characters `.dat`. `snprintf()` would null terminated it for me?

Comment: `snprintf(targetP->output_filename_serial_log, (strlen(targetP->output_filename)-4), targetP->output_filename);`